# Why won't draft-js / react-rte load an iframe in the text editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, draftjs, rte

I'm trying to pass an iframe as html to the text editor. So when user selects a video, it pops an embedded youtube frame in there.

But `<iframe..` won't render in the `RichTextEditor.createValueFromString(html, 'html')` results.

eg:

`const foo = '<h1>i am a headline</h1>';`

`const html = foo.concat('<p>i am a paragraph</p>');`

Passing `html` to `createValueFromString()` and setting that to `state.value` so the text editor takes it as its value - renders both fine. That all works.

But changing `const html = foo.concat('<iframe height="300" width="300"></iframe>');` just renders a headline. No trace of iframe.

Is there something i'm missing? answers on rte, draft-js and specific to iframe seem very rare.

Comment: draftjs support little html tags